# How to split list element according to place value

Tags: python, list, split, integer, csv

I'm trying to slit the year, month, and control number from a group of numbers.

```
s = ['201911007', '201203008']
my expected output
year=['2019', '2012']
month=['11','01']
controlnum=['007','008']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = ['201911007', '201203008']
year = []
month = []
controlnum = []
for number in s:
    year.append(number[:4])
    month.append(number[4:6])
    controlnum.append(number[6:])

print(year)
print(month)
print(controlnum)
```

Comment: Good to know that.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a list comprehension to produce tuples with each part, then zip to break the tuples into separate lists:

```
s = ['201911007', '201203008']

year,month,controlNum = map(list,zip(*( (v[:4],v[4:6],v[6:]) for v in s )))
```

output:

```
print(year)
print(month)
print(controlNum)

['2019', '2012']
['11', '03']
['007', '008']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a function

```
s = ['201911007', '201203008']
def info(s):
     return [i[:4] for i in s], [i[4:s] for i in a], [i[6:] for i in s]
year, month, controlnum = defo(s)
print (year)
```